# These animals can usually be dangerous

Tags: modal-verbs

1. *These animals **can** be dangerous*.

Sentence 1) can be glossed as:

2. *These animals are **sometimes** dangerous*. Or
3. ***Some of these** animals are dangerous*.

We can also add the adverb of frequency "sometimes" to sentence 1) to make it clear which meaning we intend to imply:

4. *These animals **can sometimes** be dangerous*.

Q: Can we use the frequency adverb "always" or "usually" with "can":

5. *These animals **can always** be dangerous.*
6. *These animals **can usually** be dangerous.*

Comment: You need to realise that (1) If the animals 'can be dangerous', they **are** dangerous. They _may_ (not necessarily _will_, this very day,) cause harm. (2) English often uses words in a less than well-defined sense. 'This bottle is more full than that one' (for 'more nearly full'). That said, (5) sounds acceptable as a middle-strength warning, but (6) sounds unnatural. '... are often dangerous' sounds more natural, as a high-strength warning, though again 'are dangerous and often attack' is more logical.

Comment: *These animals / people / problems **can usually be ignored*** works okay (***ignored*** being a meaningful past tense verb referencing an action that ***can usually*** be taken). Whereas *Arsenic **can usually be poisonous*** (***poisonous*** being a straightforward adjective) doesn't work. But I don't think that's because arsenic ***is*** poisonous (as in "it either ***is*** or it ***isn't;*** there's no scope for ***may*** be). I think it's because *Can usually be X* is some kind of "positive polarity" item. *Arsenic can usually be **obtained*** works too, which is something to think about.

Comment: In consideration of which I've just retracted my "Migrate to ELL" vote. I can't succinctly explain why some variations of ***X can usually be Y*** work, but others don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, *These animals / people / problems can **sometimes/always** be ignored*---Does this  work?

Comment: **Always** has several meanings, not all of them “of frequency”: **1** *He can always (upon all occasions) be relied upon to give a good answer.* **2** *You can always (in any case; as a last resort) buy a new one if that breaks.* **3** *It might be an investment but prices can always (at any [given] time) fall.* **4** *Your love means that I can always (forever) feel this way.*

Comment: @Mr.X: We could be here forever with you asking about specific permutations of *[noun phrase] CAN **sometimes / always / usually /  seldom / rarely / ...** BE **ignored / obtained / poisonous / disappointing / ...*** At the end of the day we need someone to summarize the *principles* involved here - which currently I'm not consciously aware of, even though I'd probably have little hesitation in *applying* those principles to specific permutations.